# Laravel: JSON encode/decode html tags

Tags: php, json, laravel

here is my flow and issue.

I have table A with fields:

- someStringField
- someStringHtmlField

I am writing a row from table A to table B in a field using Ajax. I am not using any JSON encode/decode functions, Laravel automatically converts it by using $casts in my model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'someStringHtmlField' => 'array',
];
```

So this is my record in database:

```
{ "someStringField" : "something", "someStringHtmlField" : "Some<br \/>break" }
```

When I am outputting this in my view, I am getting

```
Some<br />break"
```

instead of

```
Some
title
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Are you doing this {{ $someStringHtmlField }} ? if so you need to do {!! $someStringHtmlField !!} since Laravel automaticlly strips html and script tags

Comment: I am using <% this %> as I am also using AngularJS and the syntax is in conflict with Laravel.

Comment: It seems to me that Laravel is escaping your strings automatically or maybe you have your strings encoded. Can't help much more, you have to do some tests. Try doing a <?php echo $someStringHtmlField ?> just to ensure that the problem is in fact with laravel and not your string

Comment: Thank you for your effort. If I try <?php echo $someStringHtmlField ?>, I get the right output. Although, I still can not proper use it. It gets wrong by using <% $someStringHtmlField %> or <%! $someStringHtmlField !%>. These are my settings: Blade::setContentTags('<%!', '!%>') and Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%', '%>'). Any ideas more?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the part of the view where you actually display this

Answer (score 0):

As a  workaround method you have to convert that into an array and embed that into your View.

For instance in my case:

```
    $arr=[];
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        $arr[]=  $r->id.' '.$r->egasi. ' ' . $r->raqam . ' ' . $r->created_at;
    }
    return view('welcome', compact('arr'))->render();
```

and then in the blade  put in:

```
    @foreach($arra as $i)
      <h1> {{$i}}<h1>
    @endforeach
```

**Or probably instead of foreach stuff  use a < p /> for each string**